# install cordova 3.0.4 or 3.2.0 using npm on ubuntu

Tags: cordova, npm, cordova-3

I'm trying to install Latest cord-ova version on my Ubuntu 12.04 system. But getting version 2.8.1 always.

How can I get latest version using npm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to run the following to get the latest stable release (3.3.0).

```
$ sudo npm update -g cordova
```

If not NPM syntax to install a specific version (3.0.4 or 3.2.0).

```
$ sudo npm install -g cordova@3.2.0
```

Be sure to run 'update' on any platforms in your project directory.

```
$ cordova platform update android
$ cordova platform update ios
$ ... any other platforms ...
```

If you are still having trouble you might want to uninstall cordova via NPM, clean-up, and reinstall.